# Is there a pre-read event for mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to run a method every time I read from a Schema. Something like this:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var exampleSchema = new Schema({
    views: {
        type: Number
    }
});

exampleSchema.pre('read', function(next) {
    this.views++;
    next();
});
```

Alternatively if there is a better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you define _"read"_?

Comment: @robertklep Sorry if that's the incorrect terminology, I'm not a native english speaker. I meant a query that reads from the database.. but any query type whatsoever would work for me too. Technically, I'm using node-restful and would like to run this method everytime a GET request is sent to the API.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not a native speaker either :) I think you want more than just what you're showing, though, as I assume that you want the value of `views` to be updated in the database too? I don't know `node-restful`, but from the documentation it looks like you may be able to use [`Resource.after('get', ...)`](https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful#api).

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I based my example on the pre 'save' function in mongoose, but now that you mention it I see more logic is required in this case. I'm not sure how I would go about updating `views` in the database though, in fact i'm not sure it's possible. Do you have any advice for an alternate method? Thanks. EDIT- Sorry didn't see your edit. Will take a look at the node-restful docs.

Comment: @robertklep. Ah, this is rather embarrassing. Not once did I while pouring through the mongoose docs think about taking a look at the documentation for node-restful. That is a perfect solution for me. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!